# Convert String to Method for use with Datetime

Tags: apex, datetime, string

How do I convert a string into a method? I am building a method in a string using custom setting variables.

```
    Datetime now = Datetime.now();

    update_settings__c updateSettings = [SELECT Date_Range_Type__c, Date_Range_Number__c, Date_Iterations__c, Batch_Size__c FROM update_settings__c];

    string endtimeBuilder = 'now' + updateSettings.Date_Range_Type__c + '(' + updateSettings.Date_Range_Number__c + '*(i-1));';

    system.debug(endtimeBuilder);
```

This will log:

> now.addDays(3*(i-1));

Which is what I want... but I want to be able to use it as a method. Ex:

```
datetime trueDateTime = endtimeBuilder;
```

*I have a feeling this really isn't a method and my terminology is off. There may be an existing answer that I'm not seeing due to this.*

Comment: The closest term I can think of for what you are describing is "dynamic evaluation" (like the `eval()` function in Javascript, which can interpret a string as if it were code). The `datetime trueDateTime = endtimeBuilder;` construction (which looks like storing a reference to a method in a variable) would rely on methods being _first-class citizens_. Methods are not first-class citizens in Apex (but they are in Javascript).

Comment: @DerekF What you are describing is what I was looking for. Dynamic evaluation sounds like the right term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you want to do that sort of dynamic logic you need to do one of the following:

1. Use an `if`/`else` chain to determine behavior
2. use custom classes implementing a common interface
3. call out to the Tooling API to execute an anonymous script
4. once the summer release rolls out to your org, you can implement a `switch` statement

Door #3 would be exorbitantly expensive for a simple call like this one. So right now the first option may be simplest:

```
Datetime endTime;
Integer toAdd = rangeLength*(i-1);
if (rangeType == 'Days')
{
    endTime = now.addDays(toAdd);
}
else if (rangeType == 'Months')
{
    endTime = now.addMonths(toAdd);
}
// etc.
```

Once the switch statement rolls out, it should simplify to something like:

```
switch on rangeType
{
    when 'Days' { endTime = now.addDays(toAdd); }
    when 'Months' { endTime = now.addMonths(toAdd); }
    when 'Years' { endTime = now.addYear(toAdd); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the switch statement. I'm going to roll with that.

Comment: @S.B. Just know it's not GA yet and next release is only targeted, not confirmed by any means.